# Grails 3.3.3 war deployed on tomcat 8.5 issue with closed jdbc connection

Tags: sqlexception, grails3, tomcat8.5, tomcat-jdbc

When I run the war file in the container, it appears as the connection dropped on the server side (default idle timeout there is 8h) leads to exceptions (root cause: connection already closed / the last successful package to the server was sent either 0ms ago or a value representing >8h. those exceptions are not recoverable until restarting the container.

Problem 1) when adding the jdbc-tomcat pool as dependency in build.grade
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
re-connections to disconnected "other than the main" dataSource (below dataSources) are not attempted. regardless of those properties:
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    properties:
        initialSize: 2 # connection pool size
        maxActive: 10
        minIdle: 0
        maxIdle: 10
        removeAbandonedTimeout: 120 # free connection used by quartz job
        removeAbandoned: true
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
        testOnBorrow: true
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
        defaultTransactionIsolation: java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
"other" DS are supported fully in terms of pooling in the grails/tomcat combination.

So, I removed tomcat-jdbc from gradle and put after every url ?autoReconnect=true.
Still, some of the properties influence.
    properties:
        initialSize: 2 # connection pool size
        maxActive: 20
        minIdle: 2
        maxIdle: 20
the values above caused, after 20 calls within a closure using 20 times a connection (sequentially, not in parallel) the 21st one to fail. at the whole time, watching the open connections on mariadb side there was zero or one concurrent conns.
after removing the properties it worked. why do this values influence when conn pool is not loaded?

Tomcat comes with its own tomcat-jdbc jar, which could make a difference.
is it required to change type to "provided" in build.grade, just like for tomcat itself?

Problem 2) is, web findings, i.e. also in this forum, but also grails documentation itself point to https://grails.org/deployment. doc mentions caveats when deploying to containers being documented there...but when I register, I get no confirmation email and the page forwards to https://grails.org/unauthorized. it appears to me as if the registration is broken. Is there an email contact for that - couldn't find any.

I just can't believe that this takes me so long to have a plain pool in a web container. Things worked fin also in the old container version

Answer (score 0):

Found it. it was due to 3 problems:

1. gradle dependency type for tomcat-jdbc must be provided and not compile to avoid conflict (lib part of tomcat installation)
2. in application.yml (and local file overloading content of application.yml) properties below "dataSource:" for pooling were not in inherited by other datasources (defined below anchor "dataSources:")
3. if an action is not completed within removeAbandonedTimeout: 60
   (seconds), the connections are ripped back which triggered the
   connection failure exceptions. increased the value. unfortunately it
   was invisible since removeAdbandoned was set to true, but not so
   logAbandoned.